# How to get HTML5 JavaScript canvas to recognize touch/tap from iphone/ipad?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have a very simple HTML5 game that works as expected from a regular browser, but when accessed from a browser on an iPhone or iPad, it does not recognize the click event or the touchstart event.

The original code is from a tutorial located here:
http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/

I have modified it and added a click event which will move the smiley face to wherever you click on the canvas. This click event works fine from Mac and Windows browsers with a mouse:
http://iwebss.com/test

But if you access it with an iPhone or iPad, the click event does not work. I also tried adding an additional listener for touchstart, which does not work either.

These are the new listeners I added to the code:

```
    addEventListener("click", mouseClickEvent, false);
    function mouseClickEvent(e) {
        alert("click event");
            mouseClick = true;
        if (e.offsetX) {
              mouseX = e.offsetX;
              mouseY = e.offsetY;
            }  else if(e.layerX) {
              mouseX = e.layerX;
              mouseY = e.layerY;
            }
    }

    addEventListener("touchstart", testEvent, false);
    function testEvent(e) {
        alert("touchstart event");
    }
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong, or how to read iPhone and iPad touch events?

EDIT: I also tried the mousedown event which also does not work.

RESOLVED: I figured it out... see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out ... although the event listener works in a regualr browser, for iphone/ipad you need to specifically attach it to the canvas.

So in my given example, I have:

`var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");`

So this worked in regular browsers, but **NOT** on iphone/ipad:

`addEventListener("click", mouseClickEvent, false);`

**SOLUTION:** This is what I had to do to get it to work on iphone/ipad (add the canvas. in front):

`canvas.addEventListener("click", mouseClickEvent, false);`

This also worked for the touchstart event as well!

As a side note, I wonder if it matters whether you use touchstart or click event on iphone??

Answer (score 5):

Handlers to attach are:

```
ontouchstart - a finger goes down.
ontouchmove - a finger moves.
ontouchend - a finger goes up.

ongesturestart - a scale or a rotation starts.
ongesturechange - a scale or a rotation.
ongestureend - a scale or a rotation ends.
```

Several meta iOS-specific meta tags along with other info [here](http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/).

Comment: In javascript itself though, you do not use the on part ... so for onclick handler, in javascript you just use click and for ontouchstart in javascript you just use touchstart.

Comment: Yes. I have added handlers to the buttons ontouchstart="" etc. It refuses to work when the href attribute is also specified I think. So, I used JS to blank out the HREF attribute and add that info to ontouchstart, for all links. That got it working.